# モバイルデータの上限に達しているかどうかを調べるAPIはありますか？

Tags: android

[image: モバイルデータ使用量がオーバーで制限中]
モバイルデータ使用量がオーバーで制限中の状態はandroidAPIなどで判別することも可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

設定アプリや制限時のダイアログ表示のFrameworkのソースを確認してみた所
NetworkPolicyManager.getNetworkPolicies()から取得できるNetworkPolicyクラスのisOverLimit()を使うことで参照できそうですが

NetworkPolicyManagerクラスもNetworkPolicyクラスもpublicではあるものの@hideなクラスのため公開APIではなく、ハードルは高そうです。
リフレクションを使うことで使用可能とは思いますが、正規の方法ではないのでAndroidのバージョン等によって動きが保証されないと思います

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます、NetworkPolicyのクラスを利用するにはシステパーミッションも必要みたいで。。厳しいですねjava.lang.SecurityException: NetworkPolicy: Neither user 10180 nor current process has android.permission.MANAGE_NETWORK_POLICY.

Comment: MANAGE_NETWORK_POLICYの権限はsignatureなので一般アプリからは使用不可でしたね・・・先にこちらを確認すべきでした。お手数かけました。